# What to say in a situation like this?

Tags: phrases

Basically I want to know a phrase to tell someone who is very sure about his opinion, stubborn and doesn't want to change it, although he is wrong?

I want something like "yeah sure man, you're right", I don't want to continue arguing with him and just tell him he's right, without it sounding so mean, something you can say to a manager, but without it sounding so respectful, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is best addressed in workplace.SE, or a similar site.

Comment: Maybe [interpersonal.se]

Comment: @jimm101 If you put `[]` around `workplace.se` it will automatically create a link with the full site name, i.e. [workplace.se].

Answer (score 0):

"One plus one is three."

"Hm."

"Hm" is most neutral and least upsetting I've heard.

If you say "right" or "sure," most people will understand you don't take them seriously and they may just get mad.